# Cannot find the declaration of element 'company

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation

I am trying to write XSD for the following XML, but it shows the error:-
Exception: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'company

**company.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Companies
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.w3schools.org companyxsd.xsd">

    <Company>
        <Companyname></Companyname>
        <address></address>
    </Company>    

    <Department>
        <dname></dname>
        <deptphoneno></deptphoneno>
        <deptfaxno></deptfaxno>
        <deptemail></deptemail>
    </Department>   

    <Employee>
        <empid></empid>
        <ename></ename>
        <emailid></emailid>
        <phoneno></phoneno>
    </Employee> 

    <ContractEmployee>
        <name></name>
        <phoneno></phoneno>
    </ContractEmployee>   

    </Companies>
```

And following is my XSD file 
**companyxsd.xsd**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault = "qualified">

<xs:element name = "Companies">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs = "unbounded" minOccurs = "1" name = "Comp"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name = "Company">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "Companyname" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "address" type = "xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name = "Department">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "dname" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "deptphoneno" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "deptfaxno" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "deptemail" type = "xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name = "Employee">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "empid" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "ename" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "emailid" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "phoneno" type = "xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name = "ContractEmployee">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name = "name" type = "xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name = "phoneno" type = "xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Please tell me, where I am wrong.. I have been trying to solve this from last few days and I am really stuck here.[This ER diagram is used for the XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvTJa.png)

Answer (score 0):

change schema as listed below you did mistake in companies element

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <company xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd">
    <companyname>capgemini</companyname>
    <address>chalapathischool</address>
    <department>
    <dname>cse</dname>
    <deptphoneno>995674314</deptphoneno>
    <deptfaxno>08776</deptfaxno>
    <deptemail>gvn@gmail.com</deptemail>
    <employee>
    <empid>1</empid>
    <ename>tarun</ename>
    <emailid>tar@gmail.com</emailid>
    <phoneno>1234567890</phoneno>
    </employee>
    <contractemployee>
    <name>gvn</name>
    <phoneno>9989956882</phoneno>
    </contractemployee>
    </department>
    </company>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="company">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="companyname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="department" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="dname" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="deptphoneno" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="deptfaxno" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="deptemail" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="employee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="empid" type="xs:integer"/>
<xs:element name="ename" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="emailid" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="contractemployee" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="phoneno" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```